# Metallic Map Color Space

Tags: shaders

[image]

[image]

When applying Metallic maps what Color Space should I select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PBR textures - Metallic/Specular, Roughness/Glossiness, Height/Displacement, and Normal Maps, should be set to Non-Color. Basecolor, Emission, and AO can remain in whatever color space they use natively.